# Is yum aware of package chronology?

Tags: yum

Is [yum](http://yum.baseurl.org/) aware of package chronology?

Suppose I build a package *MY-PKG-0.40-1* and publish it in a yum repo with `createrepo --update`. Then I build another package with a lower version (from a different VCS branch), *MY-PKG-0.38-5*.

`yum list recent` seems to show the *greatest* version, not the *latest* one. However from the man page

> ```
>    yum list recent
>           List packages recently added into the repositories. This is often not
>           helpful, but what you may really want to use is
>           "yum list-updateinfo new" from the security yum plugin.
> ```

I've experimented with `list-updateinfo new` and finding little success. `yum list-updateinfo new MY-PKG` seems to return repositories the package belongs to...

What I want is something like `yum list latest MY-PKG` to return *0.38-5*, given it's the latest version published to the repository, despite having already published *0.40-1*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here is *yes*. Since yum manages RPMs and running `rpm -qi <package>` will list a `Build Date` field (which is part of the package header).

After digging around on the net, the yum python libraries, and working off some of the [code samples on the yum wiki](http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/YumCodeSnippets), I was able to code up a working sample which lists the **latest** version of a package.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys 
import yum 

package = sys.argv[1:]

yb = yum.YumBase()
yb.conf.cache = 0 # Must run as root to search packages w/o cache
pl = yb.doPackageLists(patterns=package, pkgnarrow='all', showdups=True)

print 'Searching for latest version of package: ' + str(package[0])

if pl.available:
    package = ''
    latest  = 0 
    for pkg in sorted(pl.available):
        # XXX Works with sqlitesack, unsure if it works with rpmsack
        buildtime = pkg['buildtime']

        # If we're looking at the latest package, update the version
        # and textual name for reference
        if max(latest, buildtime) == buildtime:
            latest  = buildtime
            package = pkg 

    print "Latest Package"
    print package
```